# Adding Menu and Submenu options to Window Menu in MAC using wXwidget C++

Tags: c++, macos, wxwidgets

Hi I am new to Mac using wxWidget.
I need to add a sub  menu and some menu items under the Window Menu on MAC.
I am able to do same for Window menu on PC but not on MAC.

Also, I am not getting event for click on Window Menu to the function attached with EVT_MENU_OPEN event.

Please help.

Comment: Some code showing how you add them could be useful.

Comment: Are you speaking about MDI "Window" menu provided by wxWidgets or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the question clearly. However you may have to do something like this for a menu on mac.

```
    m_menuBar = new wxMenuBar();
#if defined(__WXMAC__)  
    m_menuBar->SetAppleMenuItemLabel(wxApp::s_macAboutMenuItemId, wxT("About"));
    m_menuBar->SetAppleMenuItemLabel(wxApp::s_macWindowMenuItemId, wxT("Window"));
    m_menuBar->SetAppleMenuItemLabel(wxApp::s_macExitMenuItemId, wxT("Quit"));
#endif
```

where s_macAboutMenuItemId, s_macWindowMenuItemId, s_macExitMenuItemId are your respective menu ids defined.

and regarding not getting event for click on Window Menu to the function attached with EVT_MENU_OPEN event, check if you have correct entries(Menu id, corresponding function name) in the declared event table.